# List.append() under a loop in a list can't get a right ouput

Tags: python

Usually I do it like this:

```
a=[]
for x in range(5):
    a.append(x)
print(a)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

then I put the loop in a list

```
a=[]
L=[a.append(x) for x in range(5)]
print(L)
# [None, None, None, None, None]
```

I don't konw what's wrong with it...

Comment: The result of an `append` operation is None.  What did you expect?

Comment: You should not use a list comprehension for side effects *anyway*; a list comprehension should only be used to build a new list, not for calling unrelated methods in a loop. And just use `a = list(range(5))`.

Comment: What are you doing next? You might not even need a list, and the Python 3 `range` object is a beautiful thing that supports indexing, slicing, membership testing, all very efficiency

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `a.append(x)` is a method of the list `a` which modifies `a` in place. It returns `None`.

Interestingly you get this:

```
a=[]
L=[a.append(x) for x in range(5)]
print(L)
# [None, None, None, None, None]
print(a)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Note that `a` was updated. However, using list comprehensions like this for their side effects is not recommended since the code becomes very hard to understand.

If you want to create `L` using a list comprehension you should do this:

```
L = [x for x in range(5)]
print(L)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The best code would hovever be simply

```
L = list(range(5))
print(L)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the x is added to a but not L.

```
    a=[]
    L=[a.append(x) for x in range(5)]
    print(L)
    # [None, None, None, None, None]
    # print(a) will show what you want.
```